# Unable to create cluster with Kops command

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kops

I am having an issue while creating a k8 cluster with kops command.

This is the error i was getting when i am trying to create cluster.

```
W1104 16:31:41.803150   18534 apply_cluster.go:945] **unable to pre-create DNS records - cluster startup may be slower: Error pre-creating DNS records: InvalidChangeBatch**: [RRSet with DNS name api.dev.devops.com. is not permitted in zone uswest2.dev.devops.com., RRSet with DNS name api.internal.dev.devops.com. is not permitted in zone uswest2.dev.devops.com.]
```

commands i used to create cluster:

```
kops create cluster --cloud=aws --zones=us-west-2b --name=dev.devops.com --dns-zone=uswest2.dev.devops.com --dns private

kops update cluster --name dev.devops.com --yes
```

Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Ive tried to create cluster using kops. Could you share output of `aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name` ?
If you will try with `--dns-zone=dev.devops.com` you will get the same error?

Comment: `ubuntu@K8-management-server:~$ aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name
{
    "HostedZones": [
        {
            "ResourceRecordSetCount": 2,
            "CallerReference": "****-AC78-B9F0-A056-********1B",
            "Config": {
                "PrivateZone": true
            },
            "Id": "/hostedzone/**********MA781O3",
            "Name": "uswest2.dev.devops.com."
        }
    ],
    "IsTruncated": false,
    "MaxItems": "100"
}
`

Comment: i was getting below error when i used to --dns-zone=dev.devops.com


W1106 21:57:49.025751   22867 executor.go:130] error running task "IAMRolePolicy/masters.dev.devops.com" (9m59s remaining to succeed): error rendering PolicyDocument: error opening resource: DNS ZoneID not set
W1106 21:57:49.026066   22867 executor.go:130] error running task "IAMRolePolicy/nodes.dev.devops.com" (9m59s remaining to succeed): error rendering PolicyDocument: error opening resource: DNS ZoneID not set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have registered your `dns-zone` as `uswest2.dev.devops.com` and you are referring in command to name as `dev.devops.com`.

If you will check [this docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/getting_started/aws.md), especially [Configure DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/getting_started/aws.md#configure-dns) section, you will find that:

> In this scenario you want to contain all kubernetes records under a
>   subdomain of a domain you host in Route53. This requires creating a
>   second hosted zone in route53, and then setting up route delegation to
>   the new zone.
>
> In this example you own `example.com` and your records for Kubernetes
>   would look like
>   `etcd-us-east-1c.internal.clustername.subdomain.example.com`

You will find that based on this doc example: 
`etcd-us-east-1c.internal.clustername.subdomain.example.com`
Your `dev.devops.com` is domain and `uswest2.dev.devops.com` is your subdomain.

In [Route 53](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/examples/kops-test-route53-subdomain.md) docs you will be able find example where subdomain for `example.org` in this case was set as `kopsclustertest`

```
export ID=$(uuidgen)
echo $ID
ae852c68-78b3-41af-85ee-997fc470fd1c

aws route53 \
create-hosted-zone \
--output=json \
--name kopsclustertest.example.org \
--caller-reference $ID | \
jq .DelegationSet.NameServers

[
  "ns-1383.awsdns-44.org",
  "ns-829.awsdns-39.net",
  "ns-346.awsdns-43.com",
  "ns-1973.awsdns-54.co.uk"
]
```

At this moment:
**subdomain:** `kopsclustertest`
**domain:** `example.org`

A few chapters below you will find **KOPS CLUSTER CREATION** section.

```
kops create cluster \
--cloud=aws \
--master-zones=us-east-1a,us-east-1b,us-east-1c \
--zones=us-east-1a,us-east-1b,us-east-1c \
--node-count=2 \
--node-size=t2.micro \
--master-size=t2.micro \
${NAME}
```

with information that

> The environment variable ${NAME} was previously exported with our
>   cluster name: `mycluster01.kopsclustertest.example.org`.

It means that before `subdomain.domain` you need to specify your cluster name.

In short, in flag `--name` you must specify:
`<your_cluster_name>.subdomain.domain`

Please try:

`kops create cluster --cloud=aws --zones=us-west-2b --name=my-cluster.uswest2.dev.devops.com --dns-zone=uswest2.dev.devops.com --dns private`

Comment: Hi @PjoterS..

Thanks so much for helping..Command you provided is worked and thanks again for explaining about DNS and Route 53

Comment: Hi @PjoterS, Thanks, it helped me. My name servers are in google and my domain is valid, as I put "Host -t -NS mydomain.com" and it shows the namesevrers. But when I use kops to spin up the cluster, it throws error as it can't find DNS names. So does that mean I need to use amazon's nameservers ?